# escape special characters inside json from a data attribute

Tags: json, special-characters

I have json stored in data attributes.

```
<div data-dataarray="[[&quot;Shipper&quot;,&quot;Ship No&quot;,&quot;Weight&quot;],[&quot;1WWWQUICK\PARTSCOM&quot;,1,1]]">

data = $('#'+moduleId).data('dataarray')
```

So data is now a string.

Which I then need to parse to get it back to json:

```
jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
```

This json can have special characters (notice the backslash)... which causes an error. How can I escape them before/while parsing?

Comment: please post a sample of your string data json

Comment: @viper - added data attribute example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

firstly 
I think the html5 data attributes need to have a form like data-xyzUserVariable. then you retrieve them using jquery.data("#xyz_id", "xyzUserVariable"),

secondly 
However, be wary that jQuery cleverly attempts to convert the data to a suitable type (booleans, numbers, objects, arrays or null) and avoids touching the DOM.

thirdly 
your json seems to be an array of objects ..is it missing an ending bracket ']' ?

Comment: Thanks, my code is like that but my example was wrong. Fixed it.

Comment: in your json ,   the data in first element  of the array is also an array since it is enclosed in square brackets.  the object inside this array has an undefined as it is not a primitive like a number or a string enclosed in quotes . i.e &quot;Shipper&quot;,&quot;Ship No&quot;,&quot;Weight&quot;     shouldn't this be in quotes '&quot;Shipper&quot;,&quot;Ship No&quot;,&quot;Weight&quot;'  then your parser should work. After that, once you retrieve the string with special characters you can escape them to get the html in them.

Comment: Thanks Viper. The code is all working until a user enters a special character which goes into this data-dataarray attribute. What I need to do is escape special characters that I get out of the data-attribute... before I JSON.parse it I guess.

Comment: if your problem is only with backslash. once you get the data object,  replace all backslashes with two of them to get expected results from the parser. ie. str.replaceAll(/\/g,"\\");